# Making Java Class non-final via Reflection API

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Java class similar to the following one:

```
public final class Node {
    public Node() {}
}
```

I have learned already how to change change the accessibility of 'final' fields via the reflection API, but is this also possible for classes?
Can I turn a final class into a non-final class at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

You can re-write a class file using a library like ASM.

There may be no point changing the `final` status of a class at runtime as it needs to be non-final at compile time to compile a sub-class.

Comment: I don't know what use case user982247 had in mind, but trying to proxy an object is one reason one might want to try to change a class to non-final at runtime, without having any compile time issues.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to use a `final` class using *mockito* to test, and this is a good use case to circumvent `final`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Thanks to the comment of @kriegaex. 'accessFlags' field only exists in Class class implementation in Android SDK. Therefore, unless you are developing for Android, this solution will not work for you since such a field does not exist in the first place.

Here is how you can make the class extendable by removing the 'final' modifier:

```
Class classClass = Class.class;

Field accessFlagsField = classClass.getDeclaredField("accessFlags");

accessFlagsField.setAccessible(true);

Class nodeClass = Node.class;

accessFlagsField.setInt(nodeClass, nodeClass.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
```

I do not agree with the answers above. One might want to remove the 'final' modifier to extend the class during runtime by using 'ASM' or libraries like 'byte-buddy'. I agree that if it is a final class, it is probably for a good reason but custom business logic may require to do so.

Comment: Java class `Class` has not field named `accessFlags`. Your code does not work.

Comment: @kriegaex could you check [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/java/lang/Class.java;l=108?q=java.lang.class). Go to line 184. I actually needed such a modification and it did work in my case. Not all Java Class class implementations may not have such a field. Let me check.

Comment: This is "Dalvik" code, i.e. some kind of Android stuff, not normal Java, as you also say in your updated answer. As the question is not tagged with _android_, I think this will not help the OP. But thanks for updating the answer and making it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this can work, because the compiler will check to see if the class you're trying to make non-final at compile time.  You'll get an error if you try to inherit from it.

I think it's fine to ask the question if you're curious, but the larger question to ask yourself is why do you want to do this?  Reflection allows you to do a lot of things to get around final, private, etc., but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.  If the designer of a 3rd party library thought that final was a good idea, you might be well advised to honor that.